# Why I can't ask for permissions in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have this line, I want to ask for some permissions

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
```

Everything is fine, I changed the manifest, but the "permission" after the Manifest.permission is red, and showing as an error.

I'm following an Udemy course, the guy did it exactly like me, and he has no problem.

By the way, I'm writing that code inside a function, which is outside the onCreate, but inside the MainClass, so I don't get what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `import android.Manifest` to your list of imports, so that the compiler knows where the right `Manifest` comes from. My guess is that you have something else named `Manifest` in your `import` list.

So, for example, in [this class](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/blob/vFINAL/ContentEditor/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/contenteditor/MainActivity.kt) from [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/blob/vFINAL/ContentEditor), I have that `import` statement. I can then use `Manifest.permission`, such as:

```kotlin
requestPerm.launch(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
```

(FWIW, that sample is covered in [this section](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-permissions-002.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack))